# Firebase CLI: firebase projects:create fails to create new project

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cli

Installed `firebase-tools` version `10.0.1` using `npm` and run the following command:

**Command:**

```
firebase projects:create
? Please specify a unique project id (warning: cannot be modified afterward) [6-30 characters]:
tour-of-heroes
? What would you like to call your project? (defaults to your project ID) Tour of Heroes
```

**Error:**

> `Error: Failed to create project because there is already a project with ID tour-of-heroes. Please try again with a unique  project ID.`

I tried the same with different project ID and names but getting same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message tells you what is wrong:

> there is already a project with ID tour-of-heroes

Project IDs have to be globally unique within all Firebase projects (o across all users) and a project named `tour-of-heroes` already exists.

The error message also tells you what to do:

> Please try again with a unique project ID.

The suggestion to use the console is precisely because that will ensure your project ID is unique amongst all Firebase projects.

If you want to use the CLI, it is up to you to use a unique project ID - for example by adding a unique suffix (e.g. `tour-of-heroes-20220109` or `yousafs-tour-of-heroes`).

Comment: means project ID don't check my all `Firebase` projects only? it checks all projects globally defined on google cloud with project ID?

Comment: Correct, project IDs are shared between all developers. When user of your app connects to your Firebase project, they only specify the project ID and nothing that identifies you (the developer). So it has to be a globally unique lookup.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It cleared my confusion.
This error: `Failed to create project because there is already a project with ID tour-of-heroes. Please try again with a unique  project ID.` is ambiguous for user, when user run command `project:list` sees no project with given project Id in own console. 
so I think error message should be more clear as given here about project parameters.
https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects#resource:-project

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot start a new project this way I would suggest to create a project directly from Firebase console at this link: https://firebase.google.com/?gclsrc=ds&gclsrc=ds&gclid=CJOyiZ-0pPUCFUZCHQkdxlMPRA

Then go in a folder where you want your project and type the command:

```
firebase init
```

Then follow the instructions and select "Use an existing project"

Comment: I want to create project using create command provided by firebase cli